# Nested FlatList not scrolling / ScrollToIndex on FlatList not working

Tags: react-native

I asked a different question similar to this earlier in the week and I made more progress so just closing the previous and starting this one as I can't find a solution to this one either.

`this._scrollRef.scrollTo is not a function
    at VirtualizedList.scrollToIndex`

Here is the code.

```
<AnimatedFlatList
    ref={ (node) => { this._listRef = node; } }
                style={[styles.picker, styles.scroll, pickerStyle]}
                data={data}
                renderItem={this.renderItems}
                getItemLayout={(_, index) => (
                  { length: 24, offset: 24 * index, index }
                )}
                initialNumToRender={5}
                // scrollEnabled={visibleItemCount < itemCount}
                contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollContainer}
                scrollEventThrottle={2000}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.value}
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                removeClippedSubviews={false}
                indicatorStyle="white"
              />
```

At this point I'm just unsure why calling `this._listRef.getNode().scrollToIndex(...params)` is not working.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I've got it working for top level list items, but nested items throw the same error

Comment: any solution for this i am facing same one

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to replace

```js
this._scrollRef.scrollTo(...)
```

with

```js
this._scrollRef.current.scrollTo(...)
```

This is documented [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

> useRef returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.

Notice, that `getNode()` is deprecated and no longer necessary for animated components as documented [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/66e72bb4e00aafbcb9f450ed5db261d98f99f82a).

> Summary:
> Changes `createAnimatedComponent` so that a `ref` assigned to an Animated component will now be forwarded to the internal component. Previously, a ref to the internal component was accessed using the `getNode` method. The `getNode` method is now deprecated and will return the same `ref` but show a deprecation error.